# How can show the data related to logged in user in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am trying display the task related to logged in user but on my html page nothing show except the

tag data

task_controller.rb

```
 class TaskController < ApplicationController
      def all_task
       if current_user.present?
         @all_task = Task.find_by_user_id(@current_user.id)
         render template: 'task/allTask'
       end
    end
 end
```

routes.rb

```
  get 'all_task' => 'task#all_task'
```

task.erb

```
 <p>All Task</p>

 <% if user_signed_in? %>

   <%@all_task.daily_task  %>
   <%@all_task.date  %>
   <%@all_task.created_at  %>
 <%end %>
```

Comment: You don't need to invent your own CRUD verb.  The route to get all the tasks is `tasks#index` [in rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default). If you want to differentiate the URL from the normal `GET /tasks` route you could use something like `GET /user/tasks`. You also should not need to explicitly `render template: 'task/allTask'`. Follow the naming conventions and name your files in `snake_case`.

Comment: i don't want show all tasks. I just want only to show specific task, that the logged in user add

Comment: Do you expect `@all_task` to be **ONE TASK**, or **A LIST OF TASKS**? Currently it's a list, so you need to do something with `@all_task.each do |task| ....` in the view. You can call `@all_task.date`, because `@all_task` is an `Array`, not a single task.

Comment: i  shoe the eror @all_task.each . each is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by setting up an assocation between users and tasks:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_many :tasks
end
```

Then setup the route and controller:

```
get '/user/tasks', to: 'users/tasks#index', as: :user_tasks
```

```
# app/controllers/users/tasks_controller.rb
module Users
  class TasksController < ApplicationRecord
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    # display all the tasks belonging to the currently signed in user
    # GET /user/tasks
    def index
      @tasks = current_user.tasks
    end

    private

    # You don't need this if your using Devise
    def authenticate_user!
      unless current_user 
        redirect_to '/path/to/your/login', 
          notice: 'Please sign in before continuing' 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Note that when you have a route like this that displays resources that belong to the current user you should use a callback to bail early and redirect the user to sign in instead of using `if current_user.present?` and giving a response which is meaningless to the user. This code should be DRY:ed into your ApplicationController (even better yet is to not reinvent the auth wheel).

You can link to the users tasks with:

```
<% if current_user.present? %>
  <%= link_to 'My tasks', user_tasks_path %>
<% end %>
```

In your view you need to iterate across the returned tasks:

```
# app/views/users/tasks/index.html.erb
<p>All Tasks</p>

<% if @tasks.any? %>
  <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
    <%= task.daily_task  %>
    <%= task.date  %>
    <%= task.created_at  %>
  <% end %>
<% else %> 
  <p>You don't have any tasks.</p>
<% end %>
```

You can cut duplication here by using partials.

Comment: Are you even accessing the right URL? `/user/tasks` not `/all_tasks`. This is meant to replace your existing code.

Comment: i am accessing /user/tasks that's why it showing template otherwise rails raise the route error

Comment: Does the user even have any tasks?

Comment: yup i add 5 task it's save in db

Comment: Yes, but do they have the correct user_id to setup the assocation? Add a breakpoint with byebug and try `current_user.tasks`.

Comment: I have no idea whats going on. And the problem is not in the code provided here.  If all the `daily_task`, `date` columns are nil you would get just blank space rendered as there is no markup like a table or unordered list. I would encourage you to write an actual test which creates the tasks and then calls the controller and then write assertions about the rendered content. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69103101/how-can-destroy-all-task-linked-to-login-user-in-rails/69103317#69103317

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure if the instance variable @current_user is defined? If not, try the following:

```
 class TaskController < ApplicationController
      def all_task
       if current_user.present?
         @all_task = Task.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
         render template: 'task/allTask'
       end
    end
 end
```

instead of

```
 class TaskController < ApplicationController
      def all_task
       if current_user.present?
         @all_task = Task.find_by_user_id(@current_user.id)
         render template: 'task/allTask'
       end
    end
 end
```

Comment: it show the 2 error curent_user not found and also in erb file each is undefined

Comment: This means that the current_user is not defined. It depends on your authentication functionality how you built it. You need to define it first to access the login/current_user data.