# how can destroy all task linked to login user in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to delete all task that is linked to logged in user but when I click on delete all button it shows the error

```
 No route matches [POST] "/tasks/destroy_all"
```

task_controller.rb

```
 class TaskController < ApplicationController

   def all_destory
       @user = current_user
       @user.tasks.destroy_all
       redirect_to user_tasks_path

   end
 end
```

route.rb

```
 get '/tasks/destroy_all', to: 'task#all_destory', as: :destroy_all
```

HTML

```
  <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
     <%= task.daily_task  %>
     <%= task.date  %>
  <% end%>
   <%= button_to "delete all", destroy_all_path %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTTP verb and your route must match. Currently your button is using `POST`, but your route accepts `GET`. You could change them both to `POST`.

```rb
post '/tasks/destroy_all', to: 'task#all_destory', as: :destroy_all
```

This fixes the problem in the question, but it's not ideal. As @max points out, `DELETE` would be more communicative of what clicking the button does– delete resources.

[DELETE documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE)

Comment: it just delete user_id from tasks table but the task are still in db table

Comment: @MuhammadUsman that sounds like a different problem. Does this answer allow you to call your controller method by clicking the "delete all" button?

Comment: i am new in ror i think it allow to call controller method on path

Comment: You could put a debugger statement like (pry or byebug) or just `puts 'called all_destory'` to confirm.

Comment: While this fixes the immediate problem its not great. POST in Rails flavor REST implies that you are creating a resource. And whenever you add `destroy`, `create` or `update` as part of a path a kitten dies.

Answer (score 1):

When destroying records you want to use the `DELETE` HTTP verb.

GET requests are saved in the browsers history and should not create, modify or destroy anything on the server.

Typically in Rails you just have a route to destroy a single record. But if `DELETE /things/1` deltes a single resource then `DELETE /things` should logically destroy the entire collection:

```
get '/user/tasks', to: 'users/tasks#index', as: :user_tasks
delete '/user/tasks', to: 'users/tasks#destroy_all'
```

```
# app/controllers/users/tasks_controller.rb
module Users
  class TasksController < ApplicationRecord
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    # display all the tasks belonging to the currently signed in user
    # GET /user/tasks
    def index
      @tasks = current_user.tasks
    end

    # destroy all the tasks belonging to the currently signed in user
    # DELETE /user/tasks
    def destroy_all
      @tasks = current_user.tasks
      @tasks.destroy_all
      redirect_to action: :index 
    end 

    private

    # You don't need this if your using Devise
    def authenticate_user!
      unless current_user 
        redirect_to '/path/to/your/login', 
          notice: 'Please sign in before continuing' 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
<%= button_to "Delete all", user_tasks_path, method: :delete %>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69164369/how-can-apply-authorization-in-rails-through-cancan